# App Crashing when asking location permission in marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, android-location

App **Crashing** when asking **location** permission in **marshmallow**. after crashing permission requesting dialog box is coming. clicked allow, that exiting after that. then we can open app without crash. help me to find the error .
permission request dialog box is coming more than 5 times also.

```
public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        // Asking user if explanation is needed
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                      Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)&& ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
           if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // permission was granted. Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    try {
                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("map exiting code", "mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);");
                    }
                }
            } else
                // Permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }
        // other 'case' lines to check for other permissions this app might request.
        // You can add here other case statements according to your requirement.
    }
}
```

Comment: post the log...

Comment: Also post full activity code here.

Comment: crash log?.....

Comment: i m sure that you are doing some location task before allowing permission., thats why location getting null.. it should be null pointer exception.. i guess

Comment: See my Sample https://github.com/Ludy87/AndroidPIT/tree/master/LocalLocation

Comment: Attach the log file